# .Net MVC order agnostic routing tables with multiple attributes

Tags: c#, .net, restful-url

I'm setting up a RESTful API using C# .Net. For one of my route areas, I want to give the user the ability to query any number of attributes and in any order as a way of filtering results. Right now I have 6 attributes. Is there a way to easily create an order agnostic attribute routing table that doesn't involve manually specifying all of the various combinations?

As example, I want users to be able to query using the following URLs with the first two calling the same function to give the same result:

```
/api/transactions/attr1/{attr1:int}/attr2/{attr2:int}/attr4/{attr4:int}       
/api/transactions/attr2/{attr2:int}/attr1/{attr1:int}/attr4/{attr4:int} 
/api/transactions/attr4/{attr4:int}
/api/transactions/attr6/{attr6:int}/attr3/{attr3:int}/attr5/{attr5:int}/attr2/{attr2:int}/attr1/{attr1:int}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow the user to query, you should probably be using WebAPI rather than MVC as WebAPI supports OData which is a client-side querying syntax.  For instance, you can say:

/AccountSet?$filter=OwnerId/Id eq (guid'" + SystemUserId + "')

Answer (score 0):

You should do this as `QueryString` or `Form` input. `QueryString` or `Form` input can be in any arbitrary order, whereas URLs cannot without becoming very messy.

```
/api/transactions?attr1={attr1:int}&attr2={attr2:int}&attr4={attr4:int}       
/api/transactions?attr2={attr2:int}&attr1={attr1:int}&attr4={attr4:int} 
/api/transactions?attr4={attr4:int}
/api/transactions?attr6={attr6:int}&attr3={attr3:int}&attr5={attr5:int}&attr2={attr2:int}&attr1={attr1:int}
```

You would simply route `/api/transactions` and let the model binder do the rest.